# Taylor series of ln(xy) using 2 difference approaches yields different results - how?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm studding for my math exam and I found some question I can not answer.
I have to find Taylor series of $\ln(xy)$ near  $(1,1)$
So I know that $$\ln(1-t) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n}$$
assume $1-t=xy$ then $t=1-xy$ and so $$\ln(xy)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-xy)^n}{n}$$

But, I also can write $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$
suppose $1-t=x$ (or $y$) then
$$\ln(xy)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-x)^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-y)^n}{n}$$

Two of those are not equal.How/why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series near $(1,1)$ should be in powers of $(x-1)$ and $(y-1)$.  Your second series is (essentially) of that form.  Your first series is not.  From the first  series, you will need to do
$$
1-xy = -(x-1) - (y-1) - (x-1)(y-1)
$$
and substitute that in.  A complicated calclulation.  The mixed terms $(x-1)^k(y-1)^l$ all cancel, of course.